# Pass Activity through Field instead of string input

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there any way to pass the sent Activity through the validate delegate instead of just the input string? It would be really cool if it'd be possible.

```
FormBuilder<BusinessTrip> builder = new FormBuilder<BusinessTrip>();
return builder.Field(nameof(Order.Date), "When did you order the product?", validate: async (state, input) => {
    // Do something.
})
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to get the ChannelId and ChannelData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you want to pass data from the activity to the `FormFlow`, uses the form state to store them. You can pass the data to the state when you instantiate the `FormFlow`

```
var myform = new FormDialog<MyFormState>(new MyFormState(activity.ChannelId, activity.ChannelData), BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);

context.Call<MyFormState>(myform, FormCompleteCallback);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. The FormFlow is instantiated only once, right? So during my form dialog I only have th ChannelData from the message that started the Form, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's just like any other dialog.